# Weblogic Start Failed java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/Server

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

When I try to start weblogic using startWebLogic.sh I'm getting the following error.

```
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_18/bin/java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1033/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:C:/Oracle/Middleware/patch_oepe1033/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:C:/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp353/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.Server
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: weblogic.Server.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Also have the following in the console output in the begining.

```
setDomainEnv.sh: Don't know how to set the shared library path for MINGW64_NT-6.1.
```

Comment: Your classpath is not configured correctly. The jar that contains this class is not on the classpath. Check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG282 to understand WebLogic class loading

Comment: I read those articles. Can you please elaborate more? Which library? And how to check the classpath value?

Answer (score 2):

`weblogic.jar` is the file which contains the `weblogic.server` class . 
usually the classpath for this is autmatically set by `commEnv.sh` which is called internally by  `setDomainEnv.sh` which is called when you run `startWeblogic.sh`.
there is a variable called WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH(PROFILE_CLASSPATH) which sets the value for `weblogic.jar` this value references a variable called WL_HOME.

you may want to check the values of these variables, You also might set these values explicitly if there is some discrepancy in the embedded scripts.

Let me know if any other help is required.